# simple threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a function in my GUI that takes a while to complete since it comunicates with another programm. Since I don't want to wait for it to finish everytime before resuming work with the GUI, I want to start this function as a thread.

I tried doing it like this:

```
threading.Thread(target=self.Sweep, args=Input).start()
```

but it's not doing anything, no exception, no results. If I start the function normaly it works fine

```
self.Sweep(Input)
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you determining _"results"_? You're not expecting it to return, are you?

Comment: no i see the results in the other program its comunicating with

Comment: what happens if you put some debugging prints inside self.Sweep()?

Comment: I tried both answers, same result; debugging prints aren't executed

Comment: What is the GUI toolkit you are using?

Comment: I'm using winforms with Ironpython. does that make a difference?

Comment: I think thread is not getting created and hence the function is not called, I can't tell for sure. Can you check system logs for a crash or something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's enough to solve the problem, but at least, you should make your args

```
args=(Input,)
```

in order to match it with the "direct" call.

The `args` parameter for `Thread()` is expected to be a tuple with all the arguments for the `target` function. As you have one argument, `Input`, you must match this tuple to represent this.

Answer (score 0):

The `threading` module is meant to be used in the same way as the Java equivalent.

I think you are trying to use [`thread`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html). Try this:

```
thread.start_new_thread(someFunc, ())
```

You can get some help [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) about `thread.start_new_thread`.

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like glglgl is right.

You should pass a tuple or list for "args", e.g. `args=[1]` and not `args=1`.
What happens is, you start your thread, and it immediately dies because it tries to open a sequence - args - and you pass something other than a sequence - and an exception `TypeError` is thrown.

I am suspicious about your logging - you should have seen this exception.